# On my Apple M1 Silicon Macbook, the architecture is reporting as intel instead

Tags: macos, apple-m1

I have an Apple Silicon M1 Macbook and when I run

`npx dalai alpaca install 7B` on my terminal, the installation process encounters errors which show as

```
bash-3.2$ make
Makefile:24: Your arch is announced as x86_64, but it seems to actually be ARM64. Not fixing that can lead to bad performance. For more info see: https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/issues/66#issuecomment-1282546789
sysctl: unknown oid 'machdep.cpu.leaf7_features'
I llama.cpp build info:
I UNAME_S:  Darwin
I UNAME_P:  i386
I UNAME_M:  x86_64
I CFLAGS:   -I.              -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c11   -fPIC -pthread -mf16c -DGGML_USE_ACCELERATE
I CXXFLAGS: -I. -I./examples -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -fPIC -pthread
I LDFLAGS:   -framework Accelerate
I CC:       Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
I CXX:      Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
```

This indicates that somehow it thinks my architecture is intel based when it is actually M1 based. I am wondering what could be the issue behind this? Is it that `bash` thinks my architecture is x86_64?

Comment: Did you visit the link that it tells you to see for more info?

Comment: When a Rosetta process launches something that has an x86_64 slice, then that will also run in Rosetta. Your bash seems to be running in Rosetta, so anything it launches will too.

Comment: @Siguza Thank you, how can I prevent that?

Comment: Again, did you visit the link in the error message? It has instructions on how to do that.

Comment: I did, it doesn't appear to give directions to fix it and doesn't work

Comment: It tells how to disable Rosetta in the terminal, there's even a screenshot showing how to do it so...?

Comment: I have disabled rosetta but it is still having these issues. It is not Rosetta causing issues.

Comment: @user321627 `arch -arm64 [original command]`

Comment: @Siguza Thank you, that did the trick. How can I make this default? For example, `arch -arm64 make` works but `make` doesn't

Comment: @user321627 why is your shell not running as arm64? Figure that out and fix it.

Comment: can u post the output for `uname -s` and `uname -p` and `uname -m`????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi probably from you information you are using come terminal compatibility mode with rosetta.

Follow these steps:

- Go to Application/Utilities on Finder
- Right click and Get info for opening Terminal info.
- Unflag rosetta

Open a new terminal then.

[image]

Optionally you can duplicate your terminal and renaming of one them with rosetta for intel comp.
GL

Comment: I am on iTerm and do not see a Rosetta option. I also get the same error if I am on Terminal, andI verified the Open with Rosetta is unchecked.